# Mailing editor changed, unable to save

Tags: civimail, mailing, editor

I am running CiviCRM Version 5.57.0, running on WordPress 6.1.1 running Twenty Sixteen theme.

Suddenly, I am unable to save changes to a mailing after editing it.  It appears to save, but the content remains unchanged.

I also do not see the button ("source" I believe) that would let me view and edit the message in HTML.  This makes it impossible to (among other things) format text as centered or colored.

I have tried clearing my browser cache, and disabling outside plug-ins.  No help.

Please advise asap.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Mosaico extension or not - and if you are, is this a problem with both the Mosaico based mailings and the 'traditional' mailings

Comment: if it helps to compare with https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fa%2F#/mailing/new - what are the key differences - is the wysiwyg different? if so compare what you have at https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fpreferences%2Fdisplay&reset=1